# Why does my wrapper move outside its position when i add an animation to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am doing a simple animation to my header text box which i placed in the center of the header however when i added a animation the entire wrapper move down and to the right. how do i fix this? i added a code snippet as well as a image to see where the wrapper is moved [image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.header-text-box').addClass('text-animation');
    
    
   
});
```

```css
/*--#00b300*/

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body{
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#333333;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.clearfix{zoom: 1}
.clearfix:after{
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.row{
    max-width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row-small{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section{
    padding: 80px 0;
}

h1,
h2{
    
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h2{
    font-size: 250%;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2:after{
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color:  #00919b;
    content: " ";
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------- HEADER -------------------------------*/

header{
    height: 100vh; 
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 34%, rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.69) 190%);
}


.header-text-box{
    width: 1140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}



.header-text-box h1{
    border: 5px solid #333333;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 450%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333333;
    
}

.header-text-box h3{
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #00919b;
}

.anim{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    
}

@-webkit-keyframes text-animation{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    }
    
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

@keyframes text-animation{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

.text-animation{
    -webkit-animation-name: text-animation;
    animation-name: text-animation;
    display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang = "en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/main.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Carlos Elizondo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                
                
            </nav>
            
            <div class="header-text-box anim">
                <h3>Hi. My name is </h3>
                <h1>Carlos Elizondo</h1>
                <h3>I am an aspiring web developer and current graduate</h3>
                
            </div>
            
        </header>
        
       
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
      <script src= "js/wow.min.js"></script>
      <script>new WOW().init();</script>
      <script src = "js/portfolio.js"></script>
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were few errors with positioning. The main problem was that you positioned `.header-text-box` div absolutely and added `left: 50%` property to it, which caused that basically the div was constantly moved off the left margin of the document by 50% of the parent element length.

I have just deleted that property and centered it horizontally and vertically with flex.

> **[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/60eq0jnf/)**

**Edit**: Centering some content with following code:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Is quite handy when you want to center element with minimal width, e.g. a straight, vertical line. But in such cases as yours, it doesn't work properly because it just moves the element by 50% away of the left margin of the parent element, without taking element's width into account. You can easily notice it on my attached image:

[image]

That's why you should use flexbox. However, it had some problems with compability with older browsers though, but currently the most of the modern browsers supports it and it's quite easy to implement.

Comment: @Michael_B Yeah, was writing it, but I wanted to deliver the solution to the OP asap.